# Inno setup + SQL SMO object

Tags: .net, inno-setup, smo

I have a little problem.

I have an Inno Setup installer.

And in this installer I am creating an smo object using `CreateOleObject('');`

I am creating this object to delete an sql express database.

And code below gives me an exception.

```
sqlExpressObj.Connection.ExecuteNonQuery('DROP DATABASE [' + SQLEXPRESS_DB_NAME + ']');
```

an exception:

```
"Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information"
```

`executenonquery` is taking from the `smowrap.dll` which is built for .Net Framework 4.0.!!

And the exception in dll rises at this codeblock.

```
   public static object Invoke(object _obj, string _MethodName, System.Type[] _types, object[] _params, ExceptionEventHandler _Exep)
    {
      try
      {
        System.Reflection.MethodInfo lMInfo = _obj.GetType().GetMethod(_MethodName, _types);
        return _obj.GetType().GetMethod(_MethodName, _types).Invoke(_obj, _params);
      }
```

Do anybody have any idea how to make it work fine with "drop database" or any other way to delete the database?

Comment: I found a solution.Reason was in Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll. it was built for 2.0.even in sql server 2012. So i refused com obects and started to use sqlcmd.